# REST API authentication with query string encryption

Tags: api, authentication, rest

I am building a web application that provides an API as it's primary function. I have been looking into methods for authentication but have been struggling to make a decision on what to use.

Since this will be a paid service and the API is the service, I need to make it as easy to use as possible so as not to put people off but obviously I want it to be secure. I have considered using HTTP basic authentication over SSL but would like to avoid the costs/overheads/hassle of SSL if possible early on and maybe provide it as an option later.

I like the AWS style API authentication (see [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/S3_Authentication2.html)) but the problem is I can't have users sending the query string as plain text along with a signature because the parameters may contain things like phone numbers which I think customers would rather not expose. I have thought about providing a secret key to encrypt the string which is sent along with an api key to identify the user.

What do you think the best option is to also encrypt the query string along with the request while maintaining simplicity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HTTPS. It's simple, supported by almost all client libraries, trusted, secure, and it protects the URL and payload.

Comment: I realise that in the end this may be the best path to go down, but I would really like to avoid the overheads of SSL if possible since this may well have an impact on the service provided.

Comment: OK, then keep in mind that rolling your own proprietary security system will be a cost you and your clients will have to bear, too.

Comment: Yes, you're right, that's why I am struggling to make a decision on this one. Maybe I will use HTTPS and if the performance really is affected then I will think again. Thanks for your help, Tom.